# javascript image resize and crop to compleately fill a div

Tags: javascript

After hours of searching I have found and tweaked a little bit of JavaScript here http://generationsinc.co.uk/test/java.html that is manipulating the image just exactly how I want on window resize.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function resizeImage()
{
    var window_height = document.body.clientHeight
    var window_width  = document.body.clientWidth
    var image_width   = document.images[0].width
    var image_height  = document.images[0].height
    var height_ratio  = image_height / window_height
    var width_ratio   = image_width / window_width
    if (height_ratio > width_ratio)
    {
        document.images[0].style.width  = "100%"
        document.images[0].style.height = "auto"
    }
    else
    {
        document.images[0].style.width  = "auto"
        document.images[0].style.height = "100%"
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body onresize="resizeImage()">

<img onload="resizeImage()" src="f/a.jpg">  

</body>
</html>
```

Can it (or somthing like it) be made to work the same way in a div? i.e. - keep the image as small as possible whilst completely filling the div and maintaining the aspect ratio of the image? (The div itself will be adjusting in height and width as percentages of the window size.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need JavaScript to do this, you can use pure CSS. Create a div element with a percentage width. Then put the image inside with it's width set in CSS to 100% for example.

[Example in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc77B/) *(Try dragging the edge of the JavaScript/Result border)*

Comment: thanks - the difference is that white space apperars at the bottom as you drag the sides in... try the same on the above and the image keeps resizing so that the space it is s'post to fill stays filled!

Comment: sorry - not too easy to explain - try it out and you'llsee what i meen.

Comment: Well, you said you wanted to maintain the aspect ration of the image. This solution makes sure that the image fills the biggest possible area, while still keeping the aspect ration.

Comment: yes sorry prahaps wrong use of the term - what i mean is that the image isnt squashed in any way - i think this may also be called letter boxing